# iPhone reading shared settings from a file

Tags: iphone, ios4

For my universal application, I want to keep some settings shared by diferent controllers out of my code, like font names, colors, row height information. What is the best way to do that in IOS? plist,a separete xml file, a txt file?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create som kind on settings class which you can easily write to a plist file using NSCoding.

If you make this class a singleton you then don't need to load the plist file in all the controllers. Use the create [SynthesizeSingleton.h](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) from cocoawithlove.

Comment: tnx and how and where can I define shared images

Answer (score 1):

plist file. And, also have the settings class as singleton class.